# Parking Fee Program

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, codeblocks

Write a program to calculate the parking fare for customers who park their cars in a parking lot when the following information is given:

a. A character showing the type of vehicle: C for car, B for bus and T for truck

b. An integer between 0 and 24 showing the hour the vehicle entered the lot.

c. An integer between 0 and 60 showing the minute the vehicle entered the lot.

d. An integer between 0 and 24 showing the hour the vehicle exited the lot.

e. An integer between 0 and 60 showing the minute the vehicle exited the lot.

As it’s a public lot, people are encouraged to park for only a short period of time. The management uses two different rates for each type of vehicle.

[image]

No vehicle is allowed to stay in the parking lot later that midnight; it will be towed away. There is also a GST of 6% on the parking charges.

g. Write a program that 
i.Display of an introduction message 
ii. Prompt the user to enter the relevant information. 
iii. Displays the bill using the following format.

h.  Your program will include the following criteria. 
i.  Validation of the time-in and the time out. 
ii. Use a switch statement to distinguish between the different types of vehicles. 
iii.    Use an appropriate looping statement to allow repetition of calculating the parking fare 
iv. Run your program five time with appropriate test data using Table 1

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char type; //Variable for vehicle types
    int hourIn, minuteIn, hourOut, minuteOut, entry, exit, totalParkingTime; //Variable for time
    float totalRounded, totalChargeFee, GST; //Variable for fare

    printf("Welcome to Help Parking Lot!\n"); //Introduction message

    printf("Enter type of vehicle: %c", type); //Type of vehicles: C for car, T for truck, B for bus
    scanf("%c", &type);

    switch(type)
    {
        case 'C':
            if(totalParkingTime <= 3)
                totalChargeFee = 0.8 * totalParkingTime;
            else
                totalChargeFee = 0.8 * 3 + 1.5 * (totalParkingTime - 3);
            break;

        case 'T':
            if(totalParkingTime <= 2)
                totalChargeFee = 1.5 * totalParkingTime;
            else
                totalChargeFee = 1.5 * 2 + 2.3 * (totalParkingTime - 2);
            break;

        case 'B':
            if(totalParkingTime <= 1)
                totalChargeFee = 2 * totalParkingTime;
            else
                totalChargeFee = 2 * 1 + 3.4 * (totalParkingTime - 1);
            break;
    }
    scanf("%f", &totalChargeFee);

    printf("Enter an integer between 0 and 24 showing the hour the vehicle entered the lot: %d", hourIn); //The hour of veicle enter in military format
    scanf("%d", &hourIn);
    printf("Enter an integer between 0 and 60 showing the minute the vehicle entered the lot: %d", minuteIn); //The minute of vehicle enter in military format
    scanf("%d", &minuteIn);
    printf("Enter an integer between 0 and 24 showing the hour the vehicle exited the lot: %d", hourOut); //The hour of vehicle exit in military format
    scanf("%d", &hourOut);
    printf("Enter an integer between 0 and 60 showing the minute the vehicle exited the lot: %d", minuteOut); //The minute of vehicle exit in military format
    scanf("%d", &minuteOut);

    entry = hourIn + minuteIn;
    scanf("%d", &entry);
    exit = hourOut + minuteOut;
    scanf("%d", &exit);
    totalParkingTime = exit - entry;

     //User's bill is shown here
    printf("HELP PARKING LOT CHARGE\n Type of vehicle: %c\n TIME-IN\n \t\t\t %d:%d\n TIME-OUT\n \t\t\t %d:%d\n \t\t\t------\n PARKING TIME %d:%d\n ROUNDED TOTAL \t\t\t%f\n \t\t\t------\n TOTAL CHARGE \t\t RM%.2f\n GST \t\t\t RM%.2f\n TOTAL \t\t\t RM%.2f");

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know how to make it calculate the time in and time out with hours and minutes difference and also the type of vehicles. When I run the program, the input for time has errors. But the display format is correct.

Comment: There are 60 minutes in an hour....

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. You need to figure it out on paper first. You need to subtract minutes from minutes. And if the end minutes are too small, you can turn one hour of the end hours into 60 minutes...

Comment: Easiest is to change the minutes + hours into hours and fractions since midnight

Comment: @A.nonymous you did not even try to calculate anything for `totalhours`. What will you do in reality? How many hours is it from 12:45 - 14:30? How will you calculate this? What is your problem to put exactly the same calculation and consideration into your C code?

Comment: I have seen this question before from another user. It seems to be homework. We do require students to put up a good effort before helping them. The comments suggest he should do some more thinking himself.

Answer (score 0):

Do you realise here:

```
if(type == 'C' && totalHourParked <= 3)
{
    totalChargeFee = 0.8 * totalHourParked;
}
else
{
     totalChargeFee = 1.5 * totalHourParked;
}
```

All B & T type will enter the else statement?

Before trying to code I encourage you to pick up paper and pencil and try to do some kind of pseudocode. After that, try to test it manually. If you feel comfident about it code it. Test it. If nothing of this work, THEN expose your question to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to `#include<time.h>`
then use `difftime()` which includes two params end_time and start_time
`difftime(end_time, start_time);` but you have to convert your hourIn, minIn and hourOut, minOut to time and put them in start_time variable and end_time variable.
after you get the time difference then you can calculate for the totalChargeFee

Comment: If he already has hours and minutes, why should he bother with functions from "time.h"? Just calculating it right away is easier than converting any time values

Comment: I assume you are able to answer it without a computer. Then how will you do it on paper?

Answer (score 0):

Are you are asking this :
Since the vehicle will not stay after midnight you can directly calculate because the hourOut will always be higher than hourIn

```
totalHourParked = hourOut - hourIn;
totalMinParked = minOut - minIn;

if(totalMinParked < 0)
{
    totalHourParked --;
    totalMinParked = 60 - totalMinParked;
}
```

`totalHourParked` will have the hours and `totalMinParked` will have the minutes.

Comment: The minutes are wrong. If the time is from 14:50 - 15:30 you will get 1 hour and 20 minutes. It should be 1 hour and -20 minutes == 40 minutes

Answer (score 0):

The C library function double difftime(time_t time1, time_t time2) returns the difference of seconds between time1 and time2 i.e. (time1 - time2).

```
double difftime(time_t time1, time_t time2)
```

Suppose if a car hour in at 0630 and hour out at 2130, so totalHourParked is 15 right?

```
if(type == 'C' && totalHourParked <= 3)
{
  totalChargeFee = 0.8 * totalHourParked;
}
else if((type == 'C' && totalHourParked > 3))
{
  totalChargeFee = 0.8 * 3 + 1.5 * (totalHourParked-3);    //first 3 hours charge 0.8 and the rest is charged with 1.5      
}
else if...
...
...
else if...
```

In this case, you have to use elseif elseif elseif to enter the right branch since you are using && where it only executes the true part when both the conditions are satisfied.

Use a switch case instead.

```
switch(type){
case 'C': if(totalHourParked <= 3)
            totalChargeFee = 0.8 * totalHourParked;   
          else
            totalChargeFee = 0.8 * 3 + 1.5 * (totalHourParked-3);
          break;
case 'T': ...
case 'B': ...
}
```

Comment: wow. you are right kuharan bhowmilk. this is also a good information and i didnt know you can use if in switch statement too. thank you i will implement this into my code later and tell if it works. thanks

Comment: How do i do the time in and out without using function?

Comment: There are several ways to do it. its not a programming thing. Its logic. Use pen and paper to solve and then code it.

Comment: I understand the question well. My problem lies in the coding. I am going to fail my assignment again

Comment: i tried the type of vehicles with switch and if statements but i dont know how to do the time part

Comment: totaltime is hour out-hour in ? what do u think about this? 
what about minutes? Think.

Comment: provide me an upvote if you think my answer has helped u.

Comment: can you help me for the looping part? how do I do that part? while(false) then try again

Comment: help me before tonight if possible

Comment: "can you help me for the looping part? how do I do that part? while(false) then try again"... which part?